# Find the element in json - Using underscore library or other way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, underscore.js

I want to find the `g:id` object in the below given array of objects

If my `g:id` is like `"g:id": "121"`

I can find the element like

```
var item = _.findWhere(obj, {'g:id': '121'});
```

But what i have is `"g:id": ["121"]` like an array. How can i find it.

Here's my array of objects.

```
[
  {
    "g:id": [
      "121"
    ],
    "g:item_group_id": [
      "90461"
    ]
  },
  {
    "g:id": [
      "129"
    ],
    "g:item_group_id": [
      "90462"
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried like this `var item = _.findWhere(jsonXML, {'g:id'.[0]: '121'});` but it is not valid.

How can i do this by underscore.js or any other way ?

Comment: could you have `"g:id": ["121", "129"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.find()` with destructuring to get the `g:id` value from the array:

```js
const arr = [{"g:id":["121"],"g:item_group_id":["90461"]},{"g:id":["129"],"g:item_group_id":["90462"]}]

const result = arr.find(({ 'g:id': [gid] }) => gid === '121')

console.log(result)
```

Another option is to use `Array.includes()` to see if the array contains the value (a must if the array may contain more the one value):

```js
const arr = [{"g:id":["121"],"g:item_group_id":["90461"]},{"g:id":["129"],"g:item_group_id":["90462"]}]

const result = arr.find(({ 'g:id': gid }) => gid.includes('121'))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: That worked like charm, thank you , accepting answer in another 7 min :-)